# C++ iterating over 2 vectors using for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

I am trying to iterate over 2 `std::vectors` using for loop, but getting error. Iterating over 1 vector works, no not sure what is going wrong when I put another iterator in `for` loop.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> x={1,2,3,4,5}, d={10,11,12,13,14},x1,x2;

    /*for (std::vector<double>::iterator it1 = x.begin(),std::vector<double>::iterator it2 = d.begin();
    it1!=x.end(),it2!=d.end(); ++it1,++it2  )
    {
        x1.push_back(*it1 + (*it2));
        x2.push_back(*it1 + (*it2));
    }*/

    for (std::vector<double>::iterator it1 = x.begin();it1!=x.end(); ++it1  )
    {
        x1.push_back(*it1 );

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The commented-out code has multiple errors : `qualified-id in declaration before ‘it2’ for (std::vector<double>::iterator it1 = x.begin(),std::vector<double>::iterator it2 = d.begin());` Can someone explain what is wrong here?

Comment: this bit `it1!=x.end(),it2!=d.end()` needs to be a boolean statement, not a comma

Comment: @dainsleif That is a boolean expression. It evaluates `it1!=x.end()`, discards the result, then evaluates and returns `it2!=d.end()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of a `for` loop is a normal declaration, just like the one above where you declare and define multiple vectors in one line. Write the type only once:

```
for (std::vector<double>::iterator it1 = x.begin(), it2 = d.begin();
     it1!=x.end() && it2!=d.end(); 
     ++it1, ++it2)
{
    x1.push_back(*it1 + (*it2));
    x2.push_back(*it1 + (*it2));
}
```

You also have an error in the loop condition: Use `&&` instead of the `,`, because otherwise this is a comma operator whose result is only the last part.

Finally, it's nowadays customary to use `auto` instead of writing out those long types:

```
for (auto it1 = x.begin(), it2 = d.begin();
     it1 != x.end() && it2 != d.end(); 
     ++it1, ++it2)
{
    x1.push_back(*it1 + (*it2));
    x2.push_back(*it1 + (*it2));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more `You also have an error in the loop condition: Use && instead of the ,, because otherwise this is a comma operator whose result is only the last part.`? Didn't get that

Comment: The comma has several distinct uses in C++. When you use it in an expression (anything that gives back a value, so not a declaration), it serves as an operator. It evaluates the expressions on both sides and returns the result of its right-hand argument. This is not what you want here – you want the logical AND! The comma operator is only used when you explicitly want to discard a result (it's very rare, usually only used when you want a side-effect in an expression where you couldn't use separate lines instead).

Answer (score 2):

When declaring multiple variables using commas (`,`), you need to specify the type only once. Change this:

```
for (std::vector<double>::iterator it1 = x.begin(), std::vector<double>::iterator it2 = d.begin();
```

to this:

```
for (std::vector<double>::iterator it1 = x.begin(), it2 = d.begin();
```

or better - since you're using `c++11`, use `auto`:

```
for (auto it1 = x.begin(), it2 = d.begin();
```

This gets rid of the compiler error, but you still have one *logic* error here:

```
it1!=x.end(),it2!=d.end(); ++it1,++it2  )
```

You are discarding the `it1!=x.end()`. In expressions, a *comma operator* evaluates every expression, but evaluates only to the last one. Change the `,` to `&&`, like so:

```
it1!=x.end() && it2!=d.end(); ++it1,++it2  )
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: Can you explain bit more why `comma` is wrong and should use `&&` instead?

Answer (score 2):

1. You have an error in the definitions in the for-loop.  You cannot provide multiple types using the comma operator when defining variables.  *i.e.* this is wrong:

   ```
   std::vector<double>::iterator it1 = x.begin(), std::vector<double>::iterator it2 = d.begin();
   ```

   To correct this, note that the iterators are the same type, and so you can just write:

   ```
   std::vector<double>::iterator it1 = x.begin(), it2 = d.begin();
   ```
2. The test condition is incorrect.  Here, the comma operator executes the first test but then ignores the result.  *i.e.* this is logically incorrect:

   ```
   it1 != x.end(), it2 != d.end();
   ```

   You should instead use the logical-and operator to ensure that the loop will terminate as soon as either condition is false:

   ```
   it1 != x.end() && it2!=d.end();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach instead of using a for loop. Wouldn't it be just as easy to do this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void printVector(const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    for (auto& v : vec)
        std::cout << v << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> x{ 1,2,3,4,5 }, d{ 10,11,12,13,14 }, 
                        x1( x.size(), 0 ), x2( x.size(), 0 );

    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), d.begin(), x1.begin(), std::plus<double>());
    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), d.begin(), x2.begin(), std::plus<double>());

    printVector(x);
    printVector(d);
    printVector(x1);
    printVector(x2);

    return 0;
}
```

It gives me this output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
10 11 12 13 14
11 13 15 17 19
11 13 15 17 19
```

As this appears to be what you are trying to achieve with the two vectors. I also think this looks cleaner with better readability. IMHO I believe this is more expressive than a for loop.