# Single iterator for 2 vectors holding different elements (c++)

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have two vectors of **same length**. One of them holds vectors of double :

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> A;
```

and the second one holds doubles

```
std::vector<double> B;
```

By "the same length" I mean that A contains as many vectors of double as B contains double.
I would like to iterate through both of them with a single iterator at the same time. I have a feeling I need to create a class to do that. Something like

```
std::vector<vector<double>>::iterator iter = A.begin();
for (A= iter.begin(); iter != A.end(); iter++)
{
 (*iter).A // I access an element of A std::vector<double>
 (*iter).B // I access an element of B (double)
}
```

I checked a similar question and this one is pretty close to what I want to do: [C++ iterating over 2 vectors using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048288/c-iterating-over-2-vectors-using-for-loop)
but in my case the iterators have two different types, respectively `std::vector<vector<double>>::iterator` and `vector<double>::iterator`, so the solution of this question does not work, but I guess it is pretty close.

How can I do it? What would be the best way?

Comment: What is the reasoning for not just using subscript? Also, you can do the same as in the supplied link, using a `while` instead of `for`.

Comment: "with a single iterator" Why? I mean, you can create a custom iterator class that holds two iterators and delegates the work to them, but this looks like a lot of work for very little benefit. Why not just use two iterators?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I do not mind using 2 iterators but how can I do it with my for loop ? Should I just use iter in the `for( iter =A.begin(); iter! = A.end(); iter++)` and update `iter2` using `iter2++` in the body of the loop ? I am interested in the best practice.

Comment: afaik there is nothing in the standard library that you can use out of the box, but there is eg `boost::zip_iterator`

Comment: @rawrex I do not have a specific reasoning in mind. I am fairly new to C++ and I though that iterator should be used for this sort of reason rather than looping with subscript (I assume you mean using i as in A[i] for subscript ?)

Comment: This is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), please describe why you need this.

Comment: only now I saw that you are linking to a related Q&A. Basically the only detail you were missing is that you need not define the iterator in the loops init-statement. It possible you should, but when not possible you don't have to

Comment: fwiw, I don't think the question is unclear or that OP needs to explain motivation more. Zipping iterators is very easy and common in other languages (python: zip). I don't think it is too surprising or confusing that someone expects it also in C++. Its rather a quirk of C++ that it isnt as straightforward as one might expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In priciple you could write a custom iterator that has a `first` and a `second` that reference elements of `A` and `B` respectively. However, custom iterators aren't simple. The easier alternative is to use a plain old index based loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < A.size() && i < B.size(); ++i)
{
     A[i]; // I access an element of A std::vector<double>
     B[i]; // I access an element of B (double)
}
```

Or use two iterators

```
auto itA = A.begin();
auto itB = B.begin();
for ( ; itA != A.end() && itB != B.end(); ++itA,++itB) {
    //...
}
```

You also might be interested in `zip_iterator` from boost or `view::zip` from the ranges-v3 library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <range/v3/view.hpp>    

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A{1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector<double> B{1.2,3.4,5.6,7.8,9.1};
    for (const auto& [a, b] : ranges::view::zip(A, B)) { 
        std::cout << a << "  " << b << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7Yc1n3jba)

The standard ranges library is based on Nieblers ranges, but so far `zip` didn't make it to the standard library yet. If I understood correctly, it is to be expected for C++23.

---

PS: Note that your `for (A= iter.begin(); iter != A.end(); iter++)` can be considered "old-fashioned". Since C++11 there are [range based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), that let you iterate elements of a container from begin till end. They go one step further in also hiding the iterators from you (they are still there) to have even less opportunities for typos. Though, just like iterator based loops are a little less flexible than index based loops, range based loops are a little less flexibe than iterator based loops. They only let you iterate from `begin` till `end`:

```
for (const auto& a : A) { 
    a; // a is a const reference to element in A
}
```

I just mention this for the sake of completeness, "zipping" two iterators into one is neither easier nor much more complicated with a range based loop as with the old iterator based loop.

Comment: Up for the external definitions of iterators for `for`, always a way to go.

Comment: @rawrex not sure if with some newer features it would be possible to declare both in the init statement. And then for symmetry rather have both outside instead of one outside the loop the other in the loop

Comment: With range-v3: `for (const auto& [a, b] : ranges::view::zip(A, B)) { /*..*/}` :-)